# Git Rebase If No One Shares Branches

Tags: git

I'm the leader of a small team that's been using Git for a while, but none of us are particularly strong experts, so we're trying to figure out the best way to work. Specifically, all of the books and sites warn against rebasing when you've already pushed work to the server. However, my reading seems to indicate that it's only a problem if others have done work based on what you've pushed.

We often push work temporarily for safe-keeping, but we don't have multiple people working on the same branches, at least for the branches were rebasing would have benefit. For example, we create a branch to fix a bug, only one person works on that branch until it's time to integrate into the main branch.

In this case, is it safe to rebase even though the code has been pushed to a central repository, or are there still possibilities for confusion and disturbance to other developers?

Pushing to the server seems to be the best way to backup work in progress (rather than days or weeks with significant code only sitting on a laptop), but that practice seems to be in direct conflict with the cleanliness you get from rebasing. I'm not so much looking for opinions on the best way to do things, but really looking for a description of issues that will arise if we rebase branches that are pushed, but that no one else has used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common recommendation *“do not rebase something that was already published”* is of course a little bit exaggerated. The underlying problem is that once a commit has been published **and then fetched** by someone else, it is somewhat of a pain to update and fix that user’s repository after the commit has been rewritten. So it is just a lot easier to make a simple to remember rule with that a team can avoid a number of problems.

It mostly applies to the common Git workflows that use a single centralized repository as the source of truth. Where a single branch is shared between multiple users. There, it is absolutely not recommended to ever change a commit that has been pushed. Because even if you think you are safe, there’s still the chance that someone already fetched it.

But for well-organized teams, where each team member uses private branches and where there is a good policy that those private branches should not be touched by others—or just that there should be no expectations for those branches—there is nothing wrong with rebasing.

There are public open source projects too, where individual team members have personal branches on the public repository that do not follow that rule. And that’s perfectly fine. You just need to make sure that it is communicated properly.

And even if you take pull requests for example: In many cases, pull requests are created from branches on the same repository or one of its forks. During the review phase, it is not uncommon that the changes are changed or rebased repeatedly. This is necessary to make the pull request work properly; but technically, it is still a rebase of a published commit.

So tl;dr: Just communicate branch intentions properly and remember not to rebase something on public and shared branches. And have no expectations to continuity on other team member’s personal branches.

Comment: Thank you...that's very helpful and exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

> However, my reading seems to indicate that it's only a problem if others have done work based on what you've pushed.

Yes, that's correct.

If you put convention in place for which branches rewinding is to be expected and make it known in the team, go ahead and rebase. I usually use convention that branches prefixed with username are playground of that team member and their creator can rewind them as they see fit. It is even possible to rewind when working in multiple people as long as you agree on it and everybody else does a rebase on the new version.

Usually once first round of review is done, rewinding is not done any more and review comments are addressed in separate commits, but notably in the development process of Linux and Git itself, commits are usually rewritten according to review comments, so even that is possible (it results in cleaner commits for when you need to bisect for a bug later, but is harder to re-review).

Comment: Thank you...if I could select both answers as solving my problem, I would.